# Java clone() shallow copy

Tags: java

The following code is not creating shallow copy as the Javadoc mentioned about `clone()` method

```
// Do the same with object arrays
obj O[] = new obj[5];
obj Oc[] = O.clone();

System.out.println("Identity hashcode of obj arrays");
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(O));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(Oc));

// check objects equalness
if(O.equals(Oc)){
  System.out.println("Objects are equal!");
}
```

Output:

```
Identity hashcode of obj arrays
2018699554
1311053135
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: try initializing objects in array then create a clone of that array.

Comment: can you add any error message you may be getting, or explain why you think the code is not behaving as you expect?

Comment: sorry, I have attached the output.

Comment: You get a different _identityHashCode_, but you think it _doesn't_ create a copy? What?

Comment: @Tom I know that it did create a copy , I was just confused about shallow and deep ones.

Comment: And what has deep copy to do here? You're not comparing the elements inside the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the output is as expected. The identity hashcodes of both arrays will be different because they are 2 different Objects (being pointed to by 2 different references) at the top level. So, the `if..` condition fails as well.

***What shallow copy means is :*** The container (Array, List etc) will be created but ht elements / references inside them will not be created newly, instead, the original references will be used / copied.

Comment: What about int arrays? I tried to do the same with int array and changes made to the member of parent array was not reflected in child's member at same index.

Comment: @RajatSaxena - Why do you expect `clone()` to return you the same instance of array. Shallow copy means you get a new object with same data as in the original object.

Comment: Your answer clears the concept. System.out.println("Identity hashcode of arrays 3rd item"); // here as the objects are not cloned, the hash codes will be same
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(O[2]));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(Oc[2]));

Answer (score 1):

You seem to expect that the cloned array will be equal to the original array, as determined by calling `O.equals(Oc)`.

But since arrays don't override `Object.equals` (JLS 10.7) this call only tests if `O == Oc`.
Therefore even if `O.equals(Oc)` does return false, this does not mean that `Oc` is not a shallow copy of `O`.

To test equality of array elements, you can use `Arrays.equals(O, Oc)`

Comment: Actually, I put that if clause when the program failed to match the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

> The clone method will return a reference to a new array, which
>   references the same objects as the source array

**HashCode of both the arrays will not be same, these two are two different objects.**